# How do enable wireless and ethenet connection in Inspiron 7420 using Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I am beginner with Ubuntu and recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as dual booting with Windows 8. I would like to continue with Ubuntu as it is amazing.  However I am straggling with internet connection. It could not be connected either the wireless nor the Ethernet.

Please help in this, I have been trying for a week but no way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to install the .inf files associated with your chipset (found within the .exe driver file) in NDISWrapper and NDISgtk. This is not a guaranteed fix, but it has a good possibility of working out for you.

Download the .exe driver file here: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=P58H7#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a newer version of Ubuntu? Newer versions often offer more and newer drivers for hardware. You have a good possibility of your wireless chipset working out of the box in 12.10